# Airflow: Could not send worker log to S3

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, airflow

I deployed Airflow webserver, scheduler, worker, and flower on my kubernetes cluster using Docker images.
Airflow version is 1.8.0.

Now I want to send worker logs to S3 and

1. Create S3 connection of Airflow from Admin UI (Just set `S3_CONN` as
   conn id, `s3` as type. Because my kubernetes cluster is running on
   AWS and all nodes have S3 access roles, it should be sufficient)
2. Set Airflow config as follows
       `remote_base_log_folder = s3://aws-logs-xxxxxxxx-us-east-1/k8s-airflow`
       `remote_log_conn_id = S3_CONN`
       `encrypt_s3_logs = False`

and first I tried creating a DAG so that it just raises an exception immediately after it's running. This works, log can be seen on S3.

So I modified so that the DAG now creates an EMR cluster and waits for it to be ready (waiting status). To do this, I restarted all 4 docker containers of airflow.

Now the DAG looks working, a cluster is started and once it's ready, DAG marked as success. **But I could see no logs on S3.**

There is no related error log on worker and web server, so I even cannot see what may cause this issue. The log just not sent.

Does anyone know if there is some restriction for remote logging of Airflow, other than this description in the official documentation?
https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/configuration.html#logs

> In the Airflow Web UI, local logs take precedence over remote logs. If
>   local logs can not be found or accessed, the remote logs will be
>   displayed. Note that logs are only sent to remote storage once a task
>   completes (including failure). In other words, remote logs for running
>   tasks are unavailable.

I didn't expect it but on success, will the logs not be sent to remote storage?

Answer (score 2):

The boto version that is installed with airflow is 2.46.1 and that version doesn't use iam instance roles.

Instead, you will have to add an access key and secret for an IAM user that has access in the extra field of your `S3_CONN` configuration

Like so:
`{"aws_access_key_id":"123456789","aws_secret_access_key":"secret12345"}`

Comment: Hmm, but in that case shouldn't any logs being sent to S3...? In my case sometime it works. I've been still experimenting and now observe that if I use `time.sleep` func in Python operator, it looks log won't be sent to S3. But not sure why yet.

Comment: maybe you can check logging level, although not configurable from the config file you can change it in the settings.py, it is fixed for future version here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1045